# how to get the sum of the data over a period of time every one month in Mongoose Framework in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, sum

I have data like this that is inputted every day

```
[
    {
        "food" : "1",
        "price" : 1000,
        "date" : "1 June"
    },
    {
        "food" : "2",
        "price" : 2000,
        "date" : "2 June"
    },

    {
        "drink" : "2",
        "price" : 4000,
        "date" : "1 July"
    },
    {
        "drink" : "1",
        "price" : 2000,
        "date" : "2 July"
    }
]
```

how can I get the total sum of each price? where data is entered every day. and I want to get the total based on the month the data was entered.

maybe it should look like this

```
[
    {
        "month" : "June",
        "totalPrice" : 3000
    },
    {
        "month" : "July",
        "totalPrice" : 6000
    }
]
```

please guide me to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function does what you need:

```js
function getTotalPriceByMonth(data) {
    const temp = {};
    // You can use for..of, if you want
    data.forEach(({ price, date }) => {
        const [day, month] = date.split(' ');
        if (month in temp) {
            temp[month].totalPrice += price; 
        } else {
            temp[month] = { month, totalPrice: price };
        }
    });

    return Object.values(temp);
}
```

As a result, the function will return:

```
[
  { month: 'June', totalPrice: 3000 },
  { month: 'July', totalPrice: 6000 }
]
```

Comment: it runs good.. but where the filter for month happen?

Comment: I did not understand what filter you are talking about. In this algorithm, I simply write the value for each month to the `temp` object, and after that I get only the values from the `temp` object, thereby obtaining the resulting array.